# How to Find the Smallest Generating Set of a Group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

- How do I find the smallest generating set for a finite group?

  - I know this is slightly undefined because there can be more than one answer. For example, $S_3$ can be generated in at least two ways (with two transpositions or with a transposition and a cycle).  Also, by saying "smallest", I mean the set with the fewest elements
  - I know I could brute force it, but that would be $2^{|G|}$ complexity just to find all the possible sets -- not even testing whether or not they generate the whole group
- Would finding this even be useful? I originally thought about it when trying to test whether two groups were isomorphic
- Some examples:

  - $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is generated by $1$
  - Dihedral groups are generated by $r$ and $\tau$
  - Symmetric groups are generated by $(1, 2)$ and $(1, 2, ..., n)$
  - $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is generated by $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$

Comment: You might find [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.05922.pdf) to be of interest. It's introduction addresses many of your questions.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$, then the smallest possible generating set has size $\leq \log_2(n)$. This bound is attained by any elementary abelian $2$-group $G = C_2 \times C_2 \times \cdots \times C_2$. There is not that much you can say in general I suppose, and in general finding the minimal size of a generating set might be difficult.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem in general. Small generating sets are useful for various purposes (such as searching for homomorphisms from the group to another group), but fortunately it is usually sufficient to find a generating set that is reasonably small, which you can do by repeated random attempts. But there are some awkward examples, like $A_5^{19}$ can be generated by 2 elements but $A_5^{20}$ cannot.